# django project, mezzanine of "from mezzanine.conf import settings"

Tags: python, settings, mezzanine

Using Mezzanine Resource, I find some files are missing in source folder, but project is not except error, i really want know why! i want know this file in where?

look:
`./mezzanine-master/mezzanine/blog/views.py` #this file import this line
"from mezzanine.conf import settings"

when i goto this ./mezzanine-master/mezzanine/conf folder and list files:

```
total 96
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 Elone  staff   416B Nov 12 15:28 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 19 Elone  staff   608B Nov 12 15:28 ..
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Elone  staff    10K Nov 12 15:28 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Elone  staff   2.2K Nov 12 15:28 admin.py
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Elone  staff   2.3K Nov 12 15:28 context_processors.py
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Elone  staff   5.3K Nov 12 15:28 forms.py
drwxr-xr-x@ 40 Elone  staff   1.3K Nov 12 15:28 locale
drwxr-xr-x@  4 Elone  staff   128B Nov 12 15:28 migrations
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Elone  staff   646B Nov 12 15:28 models.py
drwxr-xr-x@  3 Elone  staff    96B Nov 12 15:28 static
drwxr-xr-x@  3 Elone  staff    96B Nov 12 15:28 templates
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Elone  staff   8.6K Nov 12 15:28 tests.py
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Elone  staff   233B Nov 12 15:28 translation.py
```

not found settings.py file in this conf folder, i do not find this settings in where, this settings is not project settings, i know project settings in project root folder, but this settings in conf folder, who can tellde me this is what means? thinks

Answer (score 0):

In python, an `__init__.py` file shares a namespace with the directory it is in. Therefore a variable `settings` in `mezzanine/conf/__init__.py` is accessible via the same name as a file `mezzanine/conf/settings.py`would be.

In this case `mezzanine.conf.settings` is defined on the final line of `mezzanine/conf/__init__.py`:

```
settings = Settings()
```